# Log4j DailyRollingFileAppender with html format

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, log4j

I want a logger daily, but with table html format. I generated files daily but not format html, also I generated a logger with html format but only file for the aplication, are there any way to generated a logger that generate a file daily with html format?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the XML configuration file, can be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="log.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout">
            <param name="locationInfo" value="true" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="TRACE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```